# How to use only a portion of a loaded bitmap with D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile?

Tags: bitmap, directx-9

I want to load only a portion of a bitmap that i'm loading from file using `D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile`.

Can someone explain to me how that would work? I've tried using a `RECT rect` with set dimensions for top, bot, right, left like this:

```
result = D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile(
    surface,            //destination surface
    NULL,               //destination palette   
    NULL,               //destination rectangle
    "legotron.bmp",     //source filename
    &rect,              //source rectangle
    D3DX_DEFAULT,       //controls how image is filtered
    0,                  //for transparency (0 for none)
    NULL);              //source image info (usuallyNULL)

   //makesure file was loaded okay
   if(!SUCCEEDED(result))
   {
       MessageBox(hwnd, "Error, result did not succeed", "Error", MB_OK);
       return false;
   }
```

But result unfortunately does not succeed. I'm sure theres an easy explanation but for the life of me i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The question was quite unclear, are you having trouble loading the image or is the image loaded but the surface does not have the portion of the texture you wanted it on?

Anyways, I assume SUCCEEDED() is a function that checks for D3D_OK returns value right? I don't see something wrong with your code maybe it has something to do with the SUCCEEDED() checking function. You're doing the image loading part right, not sure about the Source Rectangle part, if I remember correctly you should be passing a pointer to that.

Comment: Instead of loading the WHOLE bitmap, is there a way to only load a portion of the bitmap? I'm trying to use &rect to specify a rectangular section of the bitmap to show up. Does that clarify things up, or is my question still unclear?